# Parse a website in JAVA that needs scrolling to display the full content

Tags: java, html, parsing, scroll, web

I'm currently working on a program in JAVA that shall parse content out of a html page. But I can't get the whole page because it would need a scroll down to load the rest of the content.

I can see with a tool (HttpFox), that when I scroll down, a POST-Request has been send.

> Recieved:(0)
>   Method: POST
>   Type :  application/x-javascript
>   URL : https://www.justadummy.com/ajax-load-list.html/ref=ox_sc_inf_0

The URL differs from the site I want to get my content from.

Also the Params are shown:

> listType=dummyparamone&dummyparamtwo=false&page=1

The numbers increase with every scroll it loads new content.

Is there a way to simulate the scrolling with the POST-Requests or am I not allowed to use it here?

Maybe just a solution with javascript, JSoup, Ajax, etc.?

Currently I am using Apache httpclient for my Connection.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could emulate the POST request in Java and then parse the result yourself before adding it onto the current body of your request.

Comment: Do you mean, (send POST request) -> (send GET request to current site)? Where do I have to put the Params? I'm using Apache httpclient.

Comment: Well first pull the site content as you were before.  Then once you've parsed everything of interest, send the exact POST request you've found above with an altered page number.  You'll then need to parse this to get the further pages.  There's plenty of tutorials on how to send POST requests.

Comment: Well yes I've tried that. But the problem is, the URL I've found cannot be reached when I enter it for example into a browser adress bar. Just a blank page. So I guess a trigger is to be pulled. Javascript for example?

Comment: It's not going to work when you type it into a browser because your browser will send a GET request, not a POST request with the correct parameters...

Comment: Yes, you are right ^^'. So I guess logic behind this is, that the scrolling down triggers for example a javascript, and that javascript will send the POST request with the parameters. I'm going to try what you said and write if it worked. Althought I think i already did that, but maybe not without any faults.

Comment: Well, I tried it now. I'm sure that the site ist using ajax. So my conservative way does not lead to success anymore, because the html doesn't change.

Comment: What I've said to do will work, you may have just implemented it wrong.

Comment: I guess you got me wrong then. 1. The url doesn't change. 2. Loading the rest of the site doesn't change the html. The new items are not becoming part of the html. so my conclusion: 3. ajax

Comment: I'm an idiot, because I didn't use relaseConnection() before and I didn't get any content from that new request.